# naming tasks with something than URL

Tags: locust

I am testing a series of APIs and making different calls, some of which are against the same API  but  with different parameters.  Is there a way to name the tasks so the Statistics will show a name other than the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that if you follow the instructions on the link below, the task metadata can be changed to reflect a different name in the output.  It doesn't change anything in the log file, but at least you have a better sense of what is going on.

[Add support to modify request name (with dynamic parameters) through global handler](https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/825)